# First capital function using O(log n)

Tags: c

I wrote the following code to find the first capital letter in a string:

```
char first(const char str[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (isupper(str[i]))
            return str[i];
    return 0;
}
```

The code works, but I need to modify it by using O(log n) operations which is binary search I believe. How could I modify the code to follow that? Any tips/suggestions would help. (const char str[] is the string, int n is the length of the string).

EDIT: all lower case letters appear before upper case letters

Comment: Is that even possible? If you dont know anything about your input string, worst case will always be that you have to check every letter right?

Comment: If the input is an arbitrary string, it's not possible to do better than O(n) worst case. Is something else about the input known?

Comment: You can't do this, unless the input string is sorted...

Comment: ... and sorting the input string takes O(n*log n) unless you use O(n)  [Quantum Bogo Sort](https://wiki.c2.com/?QuantumBogoSort) ;-)

Comment: all lower case letters appear before upper case letters @MarcoBonelli

Comment: @Jason You should edit that in, that's an absolutely crucial detail, without which this problem is unsolvable.

Comment: Edited @Alexander

Comment: @Jason What have you tried so far? This is just a binary search where anytime you find a lowercase letter, you look "right", and anytime you hit an uppercase, you look "left", until you find the first case where a lowercase letter exists to the immediate left of a capital letter.

Comment: To get the solution in O(log n) , the prerequisite is to have a  sorted string .

Answer (score 0):

As "all" lowercase letters appear before uppercase letters, we can use binary search to find uppercase letter. Now if we find a uppercase letter then we will just check adjacent left character. If it's uppercase then obviously the first uppercase character lies to left of the currently found uppercase character. If not then we found the first uppercase character.
Otherwise we will keep searching to the right of the string.

Binary search implementation would be :

```
char first(const char str[], int n){
        int low = 0;
        int high = n-1;
        while(low<=high){
            mid=(low+high)/2;
            if(isupper(str[mid]){
                if(mid >0){ //we can't access negative index
                    if(!isupper(str[mid-1]){ //if adjacent left char is not capital, then this is first Capital char
                        return str[mid];
                    }else {
                        high=mid-1; //as this is not first Capital char, search left
                    }
                else{
                    return str[mid]; //as mid is first char of string and capital as well
                }
            }
            else {
                low=mid+1;
            }
        }
    return 0;
    }
```